# Why is OneNote hanging adding a printout?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

[image: Dialog]

I'm stuck at this dialog box. It's just hung there, and doesn't seem to be continuing to go. What can I do at this point?

**EDIT**: It seems that just printing to the OneNote printer manually has no effect. The printout finishes, but nothing happens to OneNote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this solution from the [MSDN forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officesetupdeploy/thread/0a5b5ff2-bd52-4011-95e4-c5e5c5359435/) which seemed to solve my problem:

1. Backup the registry/create a restore point/whatever.
2. Delete the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\Send To OneNote 2010`
3. Repair Office 2010.

Answer (score -2):

Give onenote and the program which u use to open your document administrative right (by checking "run this program as an administrator"). Then it should work. Otherwise you have to repair Microsoft Office.